# Total and available disk capacity in a Kafka cluster v0.8.1.1?

Tags: apache-kafka

we have Kafka cluster(v 0.8.1.1) with 6 brokers, how to monitor the disk utilization at cluster level. I want to monitor the total, available disk space at cluster level.

Answer (score 1):

Finally we came with below solution.

for x in $(/bin/cat /PATH/TO/Topic_list); do size=$(/bin/find /mnt/data*/kafka -type d  -name $x-* -exec du -c {} + | /bin/awk '/total$/ {print $1}') ; [ -n "$size" ] && printf " %-25s:%-30s:%d\n" "$HOSTNAME" "$x" "$size" ; done

NOTE: log.dir =/mnt/data1/kafka ... /mnt/data/kafka

above script was executed in all kafka brokers and consolidated per topic.